# Can i modify messageID on Azure Service Bus bindings?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

Have been working with Azure Service Bus input/output bindings with azure functions. Per the documentation the input/output bindings allow you to return strings to the output and it inserts a message into the service bus with the value of the string as the content of the message. I would like to turn on duplicate detection on the service bus but that required manual control over the MessageId property. Is there a way to access this property before sending a message to the service bus using the output binding? Instead of return a string value, is there a class I can return that i can set the body/messageid manually? The below code returns a list of strings to the service bus. There will be n messages = n strings in the list. I would like to be able to set the messageId of these messages before sending to the service bus, but since the docs use simple strings I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Isolated-Process documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=isolated-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp

```
[FunctionTestFunction]
        [ServiceBusOutput("<QueueName>", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
        public async Task<List<string>> Run([TimerTrigger("0 */10 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer)
        {

                var messages = GetMessages();
                return messages;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As of today, it is not possible with the Isolated Worker SDK.

There's a similar ask for setting message's [`CorrelationId`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/474) and a [broader issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/21884) to support setting message metadata you can subscribe to.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to possibly implement duplicate detection for the isolated worker SDK?

Comment: You won't be able to use the message de-duplication ASB feature for this reason. So, the best option will be to receive messages, note what's been received, and return early if it was already handled.